# How to switch authentication mechanism in mongo during runtime?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to test if my MongoClient has authenticated correctly using default authentication mechanism and if it's not I want to try connecting with different one.

I have following code used for openning mongo connection which uses **MONGODB-CR**:

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(this.user, this.db, this.pass.toCharArray());
ServerAddress serverAddress = new ServerAddress(this.host, this.port.intValue());
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddress, Arrays.asList(new MongoCredential[]{credential}));
```

I need to find a way to test if authentication was complete. If it was not I want to try with different mechanism - **SCRAM-SHA-1**. The problem is I dont know how to test connection. Calling most of `mongoClient` methods leads to `MongoCommandException`:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating
    at com.mongodb.connection.NativeAuthenticator.authenticate(NativeAuthenticator.java:48)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:128)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'auth failed' on server localhost:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "auth failed", "code" : 18 }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.NativeAuthenticator.authenticate(NativeAuthenticator.java:46)
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

But this is actually not an **Exception** It's just information in logs, so I'm not able to catch it.

**Any ideas how to test if MongoClient has authenticated correctly**?

Comment: Is there some reason why you cannot just issue a ["connection string"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) as opposed to the separate `Server` and `Credential` components? Seems to me that `MongoClient` will just sort out the handshake for different authentication methods for you ( as it is designed to do, for you know, "Portability" ) rather than you trying to hand roll the connection handshake yourself.

Comment: Works like a charm. Please post it as a answer, so I can accept this.